# code crashes when trying to add a vertex to existing graph

Tags: boost

I am trying to do a simple task of adding vertex to existing graph, but the code crashes:

```
typedef adjacency_matrix<undirectedS> UGraph;
graph_traits<UGraph>::vertex_descriptor u;

UGraph G(2);

int numOfComponents = 0;
int numOfVertices = 0;

numOfVertices = num_vertices(G); //numOfVertices = 2
vector<int> component(numOfVertices);
numOfComponents = connected_components(G, &component[0]); //numOfComponents = 2
```

so far it seems logical- two vertices, not connected, so there are two connected components.

now, when I try to add vertex:

```
u = vertex(3, G); //u=3
add_vertex(u,G); // <--- crashes here
```

am I missing something? how can I add vertex to existing graph? what about removing? will I see one less vertex after the command `remove_vertex(id)`?

Also, is it possible to add vertex with id of 100 instead of id 3 (not continues id number..)?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matrix. It has a fixed size (nxn where n is the number of vertices).

You cannot "address" the third vertex as it doesn't exist in the 2x2 matrix.

`add_edge` is only defined for `MutableGraph`, `MutablePropertyGraph` (with properties). `adjacency_matrix` doesn't model those concepts

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, is there example of undirected graph with add_vertex, remove_vertex, add_edge, remove edge? time complexity is important..